# Re-Ordering List Sections SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a simple List with sections that are stored inside an ObservableObject. I'd like to reorder them from another view. I have this working, and it re-orders the list sections but when you close out the app, it doesn't save the order you moved the list sections.

I want it to save the state after you re-order the sections, when I close out the app it goes back to the normal order.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sections = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"]
    
    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        sections.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State var showOrderingView = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Reorder sections") {
                self.showOrderingView = true
            }
            list
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showOrderingView) {
            OrderingView(viewModel: self.viewModel)
        }
    }

    var list: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.sections, id: \.self) { section in
                Section(header: Text(section)) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 3, id: \.self) { _ in
                        Text("Item")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct OrderingView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.sections, id: \.self) { section in
                    Text(section)
                }
                .onMove(perform: viewModel.move)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your request doesn't make sense.

Comment: You have to add a variable to the Model that saves an index. They sort by the index

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI reorder CoreData Objects in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742218/swiftui-reorder-coredata-objects-in-list)

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some options you have here. What you need in order for your app to save the states in-between sessions is data persistence.

There are several options to your disposal:

1. [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata) Recommended option to save app data.
2. [User Defaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) Older implementation and only suitable for some cases. Recommended to save for e.g. User in app settings.
3. Databases. There are a lot of options here. Your own database, Firebase etc.