# How to save the onMove order to Core Data?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I'm storing a list of a custom data type in a Core Data container and looping through them as such:

```
                ForEach(coreDataViewModel.favoriteVerses) { verse in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                        Text(verse.verse)
                    }
                }
                 // how to save this order if user closes out of app?
                .onMove(perform: { indices, newOffset in
                    coreDataViewModel.move(indices: indices, newOffset: newOffset)
                })
```

The move functionality works fine, but after clicking done and exiting out of the app, the order reverts back to the original state.

```
// CoreDataViewModel

func move(indices: IndexSet, newOffset: Int) {
   favoriteVerses.move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
}
```

Comment: have an index attribute, then sort the list by that index.

Comment: Like mentioned you need an attribute for the order, don't forget to change that attribute for all objects that are affected by the move.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742218/swiftui-reorder-coredata-objects-in-list